# Mapping a part of Memory mapped file in Windows CE

Tags: windows, windows-mobile, windows-ce

Where exactly does the address space get blocked for the MMF in the process of creating and mapping the MMF in Windows CE. Is it during the creation of MMF or when the view is getting mapped? Will the creation succeed only if there is a contiguous space of x (specified during creation) in virtual address space?

Secondly, is it possible to map a part of file in win CE like we do in win32. If I create a MMF with 0x8000 bytes and map a view of the file giving an offset of 0x5000 and size of 0x7000, the mapping is failed. It says INVALID_PARAMETER. Although the mapping is allowed when sum of offset and size of the view is less than 0x8000. Does it always get mapped from beginning of the file?

Answer (score 1):

In Windows Mobile 6.x (CE 5.0), Memory mapped files are stored in the [Large Memory Area](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms836325.aspx) above 0x42000000 in the virtual address space.

Yes, you need contiguous space to successfully allocate a MMF.

0x5000 + 0x7000 = 0xC000. That's larger than the allocated space of 0x8000 bytes.

-PaulH

**Edit**
Also, the offset [must be a multiple](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa914405.aspx) of your system's allocation granularity. Use `GetSystemInfo` to find that value. On one device I have, for instance, it is 0xa11 bytes.

Comment: But the instruction is supposed to read 0x7000 bytes starting from offset 0x5000 in file and read and store the following 0x7000 in the space allocated for MMF which is 0x8000 right? In that case, since 0x7000 is way lesser than 0x8000, why should it fail?

Comment: By "where", I meant the stage of creation of MMF. Not the location. Or it should have been "When". Does it get allocated during CreateMMF call or MapViewOfFile call?

Comment: To answer your other question, it is mapped during the MapViewOfFile call: "Creating a file-mapping object creates the potential for mapping a view of the file but does not map the view. MapViewOfFile maps a view of a file into the address space of a process."

Comment: That offset is within the file being mapped. So, if your offset is 0, then you're at the beginning of the file. If your offset is 0x400, then your 1KB in to the file and the maximum size you can map is 1KB less than your allocation.